# How to prompt for CKApplicationPermissionUserDiscoverability again

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, cloudkit

Is there a way to get iOS to prompt for CKApplicationPermissionUserDiscoverability again after the user has declined it? The most I've been able to do is remove permission in the iCloud settings pane in OS X, which just returns a deny to the iOS app without any user interaction. The app I'm writing is useless without discoverability, so I want to be able to prompt again if the user initially says no.

Answer (score 3):

On the iCloud settings of the iOS 8.1, under the iCloud Drive, there is an option called "Look Me Up By Email". There you will be able to reset the permission.

Comment: Took me ages to find! Look under: Settings App > iCloud > iDrive > Look Me Up By Email

Comment: @JoshKahane: Same here. Very frustrating.

Comment: To be a bit more exact, this doesn't provide you the ability to "reset the permission" to the initial state (no permission specified). Rather, it lets you toggle between denied and granted. To reset it to the initial sate, I think you need to do a global reset.

Answer (score 1):

In iCloud dashboard, under deployment, reset the development environment, and the next time you install the app, it will prompt again for the permission.

Warning: resetting the development environment will delete all existing records AND it will reset the record definitions to what is deployed to the production environment. So if you haven't deployed to production environment yet you can loose all your record types and custom fields in Users. I recommend deploying to production even if it's not final, then resetting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reactivate the system prompt. What you can do is test for the permissions and if it's not ok supply your own prompt asking the user to go to the settings to change the permissions.

Comment: I've been all through settings on the device and couldn't find anywhere I can change that one. I see entries for location services and notifications, but nothing about discoverability.